# How to import several EXCEL files into one single array in Matlab?

Tags: excel, matlab, import

I have a big amount (+100) of files in one folder and I want to put them all in one single array in matlab, how can i do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Loop over your files using `xlsread`, but the specifics of how you store what you gets depends on what's in the files...

Comment: The first two rows in the first spreadsheet is what i need, so first column of all files in one array, and second column of all files on another array. I started making the loop but im not sure how to set that the data from the previous file is not overwriteen.

Answer (score 0):

As seen from the OP task + the Comment

- *The first two rows in the first spreadsheet is what i need, so **first column** of all files **in one array**, and **second column** of all files on
  **another array**. I started making the loop but im not sure how to set
  that the **data** from the previous file **is not overwriteen**. –  David
  Martínez Biro 34 mins ago*

> `Loop over all filenames:`
>
> ```
>      import data, as needed, from current file into a MATLAB aCurrentArrayC1;
>
>      import data, as needed, from current file into a MATLAB aCurrentArrayC2;
>
>      aCollectionOfC1s = [aCollectionOfC1s ; aCurrentArrayC1];  %% case of VSTACK-ing
>      aCollectionOfC1s = [aCollectionOfC1s , aCurrentArrayC1];  %% case of HSTACK-ing
>
>      aCollectionOfC2s = [aCollectionOfC2s ; aCurrentArrayC2];  %% case of VSTACK-ing
>      aCollectionOfC2s = [aCollectionOfC2s , aCurrentArrayC2];  %% case of HSTACK-ing
> ```
>
> `end                                                            %% next file`

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:  Your spreadsheet is along 1 dimension, and you're trying to build a 1-d array.

This is how I would approach it:

First put the files into a single folder, e.g. 'xls'.  I start with i=3 because the first 2 indexes of dir() are "." and "..";  You need an array to append tempData to, so I put the first file into mydata and append tempdir to that for every other file.

```
Function import_spreadsheets
 listXLS = dir(path to xls folder);
 for i = 3 : length(listXLS)
     filename = strcat([path to xls folder], filesep, listXLS(i).name);
     if(i==3)
         mydata = xlsread(filename, sheet, xlRange);
     else
        tempData = xlsread(filename,sheet,xlRange);
        mydata = cat(2, mydata, tempData);
     end
 end
end
```

The number in cat() will depend on how you're spreadsheets are set up.Look [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html) for more information about cat().